# Preventing infinite loops when using INotifyPropertyChanged with a WPF treeview containing checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview, inotifypropertychanged

This is my first question so I apologise if it is not formatted perfectly.

I am new to WPF and MVVM and I have run into an issue I can't seem to figure out.

I have a treeview that displays a MenuItem hierarchy with a checkbox per MenuItem, both for Parent and Child nodes. The solution current allows a user to click on a parent node and all child items are checked / unchecked as required.

I now need to implement the reverse of this, where if a user clicks on one of the child nodes the parent node should be selected if it is not already selected.

The problem I currently have is that checking the parent node programmatically fires the INotifiedPropertyChanged event for the parent node which rechecks my child nodes.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Here is my MenuItem code:

```
public class MenuItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string _name;
        List<MenuItem> _subItems = new List<MenuItem>();
        bool _isChecked;
        MenuItem _parent;

        public List<MenuItem> SubItems
        {
            get { return _subItems; }
            set
            {
                _subItems = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SubItems");
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return _isChecked; }
            set
            {
                _isChecked = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
            }
        }

        public MenuItem Parent
        {
            get { return _parent; }
            set
            {
                _parent = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Parent");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

            if (propertyName == "IsChecked")
            {
                if (Parent == null)
                {
                    foreach (MenuItem Child in _subItems)
                        Child.IsChecked = this.IsChecked;
                }

                //if (Parent != null)
                //{
                //    Parent.IsChecked = IsChecked ? true :Parent.IsChecked;
                //}
            }
        }
    }
```

The commented code above is where I am encountering the error.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you could try to only raise the event if the value is actually different from the current value

Comment: The value should always be different. I basically need to have the PropertyChanged event only fire if it is not called from a method.

Comment: this is not the answer, but a preliminary comment about your approach. Don't implement this logic inside the RaisePropertyChanged! IMHO it is more appropriate to implement this request in the corresponding check setters... then of course the concrete answer should follow...

Comment: What error were you getting?

Comment: `List<MenuItem> SubItems` should really be `ObservableCollection<MenuItem> SubItems` with a private setter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a bit more elaborated answer based on the one already written by OP

```
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;

            if (_parent == null)
            {
                foreach (MenuItem Child in _subItems)
                {
                    Child._isChecked = this._isChecked;
                    Child.RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
                }
            }

            if (_parent != null)
            {
                _parent.NotifyChecked(_isChecked);
            }

            RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }
    public void NotifyChecked(bool childChecked) 
    { 
       _isChecked = childChecked;
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked"); 
       if (_parent != null)
       {
           _parent.NotifyChecked(_isChecked);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an other property to store if one of the children is checked. Something like IsChildChecked.

In the UI you can bind these two properties (IsChecked and IsChildChecked) to IsChecked of the node with MultiBinding. Use a converter to set it.

Comment: Along the right lines but having a local property holding the external state of the children is not a good idea, better to use a dynamic calculation such as `isChecked || Children.Any(c=>IsChecked);`

Answer (score 0):

Machine Learning's comment led me to the answer:

```
public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return _isChecked; }
            set
            {
                _isChecked = value;

                if (_parent == null)
                {
                    foreach (MenuItem Child in _subItems)
                    {
                        Child._isChecked = this._isChecked;
                        Child.RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
                    }
                }

                if (_parent != null)
                {
                     _parent._isChecked = _isChecked ? true : _parent._isChecked;
                    _parent.RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
                }

                RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
            }
        }
```

Moving the code to the setter instead of handling it in the event worked for me.

Comment: Currently my MenuItem Model and ViewModel are still contained in one class, which is why the _isChecked does not need to be private. The next step would be to split this out.

Comment: I think this code does not work as expedted... if you set the _isChecked field of the parent, NotifyPropertyChanged will not fire, so the UI will not display if the parentnode is checked. Or do I see it false?

Comment: Testing it, it works as expected. In my limited understanding of MVVM the UI will update after setting _isChecked due to RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked") being called in the last line

Comment: Yes for the child, but not for the parent.. but if it is working for you, I am happy about it... I'm only wondering.

Comment: The last line of the code calls the event for the parent, the child event is called separately in the foreach. Thanks for the assistance though.

Comment: just in case of need, one could write a `public void NotifyChecked() { RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked"); }` method that raises the PropertyChanged and is callable from outside like `_parent.NotifyChecked()` (and also a recursive helper for setting the parent of the parent ... again, if it is useful)

Comment: Just a side note, Ivoros wat correct in his previous assumption that my logic was flawed, after testing it again I needed to add another RaisePropertyChanged for the parent as well, I will update my answer. Thanks Ivoros, nice catch.

Comment: Look also at my answer if you want to make a recursive call to the parent of the parent so that it also gets checked...

Answer (score 0):

there are a few different approaches you can take,

1 Calculate the parent's is checked property

this would work by the parent listening tothe child's PropertyChanged event and then if any of them are true returning true for the parents IsChecked

```
private bool isChecked;
public bool IsChecked
{
    get{ return isChecked || Children.Any(c=>IsChecked);}
    set
    {
        isChecked = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        foreach(var child in Children)child.IsChecked
    }
}
public void Child_PropertyChanged(object sender,PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.PropertyName == "IsChecked")
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
}
```

this approach has the benefit of maintaining the parents click state independently

2 Flip 1 round and calculate the child's IsChecked property

```
private bool isChecked;
public bool IsChecked
{
    get{ return isChecked || Parent.IsChecked;}
    set
    {
        isChecked = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
    }
}
public void Parent_PropertyChanged(object sender,PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.PropertyName == "IsChecked")
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
}
```

3 Create a second route to change the status with out triggering the cascade

```
private bool isChecked;
public bool IsChecked
{
    get{ return isChecked;}
    set
    {
        SetIsChecked( value);
        foreach(var child in Children)Parent.SetIsChecked(isChecked)
    }
}
public void SetIsChecked(bool value)
{
    isChecked = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
}
```

this way as long as the children call the `SetIsChecked` method directly then the cascade is only triggered on a when the parent is set directly via the setter

**Note:** in your code you aren't handling the PropertyChanged event you are Raising it only

handling looks like this

```
public MenuItem Parent
{
    get { return _parent; }
    set
    {
        //remove old handler
        // this stops listening to the old parent if there is one
        if(_parent != null)
            _parent.PropertyChange-=Parent_PropertyChanged;

        //notice that the value of _parent changes here so _parent above is not the same as _parent used below
        _parent = value;

        //add new handler
        // this starts listening to the new parent if there is one
        if(_parent != null)
            _parent.PropertyChange+=Parent_PropertyChanged;

        RaisePropertyChanged("Parent");
    }
}
//handler
public void Parent_PropertyChanged(object sender,PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.PropertyName == "IsChecked")
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
}
```

also all of the above can bu improved by checking for if the current value has changed before making any changes

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the answer. Just a quick question. . .the handling vs raising of the event. What is the difference between the 2 and what is gained by removing the handler and then adding it again after the property has been changed?

Comment: its the difference between talking and listening, when you raise an event you shout out "THIS HAPPENED" then if there is a hander listening for that shout it will do something when it hears it, so `RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked")` is the Shout a Property has changed and `_parent.PropertyChange+=Parent_PropertyChanged;` is telling your class that when you hear the parent shout out about the property change you want to what's in `Parent_PropertyChanged`

Comment: The handler is linked to the object, if you change the parent with out removing the handler from the previous parent then you will be listening to both the new parent and the old parent